# combination of .distinct() and .sum() in java8

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an object:

```
LocalDate localDate;
int amount;
```

I have an list of those objects like:

```
{2018-01-01, 5}
{2018-01-01, 10}
{2018-01-02, 15}
```

Now what I want to achive I want to parse amount from same day.
Expected result would've list without repetitions with sum of amount's

```
{2018-01-01, 15}
{2018-01-02, 15}
```

Seems like I'm missing some stream method to do that...

Comment: That's just grouping by date and aggregating with a sum

Comment: Consider trying yourself, to then ask us with "not working code". People here are very reluctant with "here requirements, no somebody do the work and give me code. please" questions.

Comment: @ernest_k this tip should help me, I'll try my best :)

Comment: are you sure about `{2018-01-01, 26}` btw? shouldn't it be `{2018-01-01, 15}`?

Comment: @Eugene totally right, I missmatched examples

Comment: @degath you could accept the answer btw if it helped you

Comment: @Eugene I'll accept as soon as I'll check if its working properly. Give me some time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Collectors.groupingBy` with downstream collectors `Collectors.summingInt`

```
yourObjects.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                   YourObject::getLocalDate,
                   Collectors.summingInt(YourObject::getAmount)
))
```

Comment: Using your solution as input I have `List<MyObject>` and on an output I have `Map<@NotNull LocalDate, Integer>`
Is there a way to have also `List<MyObject>` on output?

Comment: @degath I dont get it, didnt you want it like that?

Comment: @degath if you want `List<MyObject>` why not call `keySet` on the resulting `Map` that you have?